# Powershell script to add local user to user profile

Tags: powershell, user-profile

Lt me know if this is possible :

i have around 100 local user and i want to add them to user profile.Can any on help me out to create scripts to add the user to user profile.

Also i want the scripts to edit any particular property for the said user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is simple code example to get you started:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$siteUrl = "http://mycoolsite/"
$accountName = "MyAccountName"

$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl 
$context = Get-SPServiceContext($site) 
$pm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

# If user profile doesn't exist create new one
if ($pm.UserExists($accountName)) {
    $userProfile = $pm.GetUserProfile($accountName) 
} else  {
    $userProfile = $pm.CreateUserProfile($accountName)
}
# Update user profile properties
$userProfile["FirstName"].Value = "Bill"
$userProfile["LastName"].Value = "Gates"
# Commit changes
$userProfile.Commit()
```

And here you have example on how to list all local users (I didn't tested it!):

- [List All Local Users](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/2327.aspx)

Comment: `New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not s
et to an instance of an object."
At line:8 char:17
+ $pm = new-object <<<<  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($co
ntext)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.NewObjectCommand` getting error .......seems i am not able to get the object of `$pm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)`

Comment: Check $site and $context objects before creating $pm - are they ok? Also check if your user have permissions on  User Profile Service Application

Comment: can you tell me how to check for permission in User Profile Service application.
I tried : “Central Administration > Manage Service Applications” > User Profile Service Application and click “Administrators” in the ribbon and assign Full control permission to the login user.

Comment: also click/check `Permissions` in the ribbon at same location

Comment: Good! If you find my answer to be helpful please take time to upvote it and/or accept it as an answer [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: v.thanks @VedranRasol ,  your code works perfectly! Appreciate your time and help.